# C++ 11 Smart Pointer Ownership and Casting

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, software-design, weak-ptr

I have a base entity class and derived classes like cows and chickens...

```
using namespace std;
class Entity
{
    list<shared_ptr<Relationship>> relationships;
    void createRelationship(weak_ptr<Entity> other,.... other stuff)
    //...
    virtual ~Entity()
}
class Cow: public Entity
{
    //...
}
class Chicken : public Entity
....etc...
```

I am trying to learn to manage memory properly with std smart pointers.  The way I am doing things now, the only place my derived classes ever live is in vectors of shared pointers like...

```
vector<shared_ptr<Cow>>
vector<shared_ptr<Chicken>>
etc.
```

My Entity class is in charge of managing relationships between any two entities, whether they have the same type or not.  To do this, it keeps a list of Relationship objects that look like...

```
class Relationship
{
  weak_ptr<Entity> from;
  weak_ptr<Entity> to;
etc....
}
```

I use weak pointers because the cows or chickens may die, and in that case their relationships with other entities should become invalid.

So here is my problem.  I store everything as shared pointers to derived classes, but all of my code in my Entity class uses weak pointers to the base class.  I will somewhat often need to convert weak Entity pointers to shared Cow pointers or shared Cow pointers down to weak Entity pointers.

Somehow, my code allows me to pass shared_ptr objects in the parameter in createRelationship(...) in the Entity class above.  I don't really know why that compiles, and I would like to know if it's efficient to do that.  Should I instead manually turn it into a weak pointer and then cast using static_pointer_cast?  (I ask this because I've read that passing shared pointers as parameters is slow, and I'm worried that's going on).

In the other direction, sometimes I know that certain relationships are between two entities of the same type.  To illustrate my point, a baby cow that needs to inherit its genetics from its parents:  It searches through its relationships to find parent-child relationships, and then gets access to weak entity pointers to its parents.  In order to access their genetic member variables, it needs to cast these weak pointers to Entities to shared pointers to Cows.  I've been using weak_ptr.lock() followed by dynamic_pointer_cast to accomplish this.

Is this the efficient way of performing these two (inversely related) casts?  Any general remarks or reference material is appreciated, because I'm trying to get a hold on using these pointers efficiently.

Comment: A `weak_ptr` has a constructor that takes a `shared_ptr`.  That is why your `createRelationship` calls work.

Comment: Passing a `shared_ptr` as a parameter is slow in comparison to passing a reference to it because it involves a copy. However, you can't just pass a shared_ptr reference and make it a weak_ptr, there has to be a copy involved anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have three main concerns:

1. Is storing `weak_ptr` efficient when you have to frequently convert to `shared_ptr` to use its value?
2. Why can you construct a `weak_ptr<T>` from a `shared_ptr<T>`?
3. Are you better off using `static_ptr_cast` or `dynamic_pointer_cast`

Question 2 is the easiest; as Vaughn mentions, `weak_ptr` has a [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr/) from `shared_ptr`.

Question 1 and 3 are much more murky. To address this, let's visit why you've heard that passing `shared_ptr` is slow. When you pass around a `shared_ptr` by value, it must copy the `shared_ptr`, and copying it involves an atomic increment of the underlying reference count. There are lots of benefits and downsides to such atomic increments, but the short version is that if you don't need to track ownership, it is an unnecessary overhead. (Worrying about this in most cases might well be premature optimization, but C++ the language wants to ensure that it's possible for you to worry about this sort of thing when it turns out to be necessary.)

What about copying a `weak_ptr` -- is that any faster than copying a `shared_ptr`? I haven't run any benchmarks, but I would guess not. There are actually two reference counts, one each for owning references (`shared_ptr` copies) and for non-owning (`weak_ptr` copies). Each of these will have the same atomic update requirements, so will not be significantly faster. I guess in theory that the destructor of the `weak_ptr` won't have to check the resulting reference count and delete the object, so that is one less branch if all you're doing is copying. But that's an unlikely usage; chances are you'll be converting back to a `shared_ptr` via `lock()`.

And that brings us back to the core of question 1. How much overhead is there to getting the `shared_ptr` from an observing `weak_ptr`? Approximately as much as the atomic reference count of copying a `shared_ptr`, plus the branch you'll require on the consuming code to ensure that it succeeded, or handle when it failed. So rather than considering efficiency here, it's better to consider ownership and object lifetimes. Will you ever be in a situation where the `lock()` will return a null `shared_ptr`? If not, chances are you can get away with an observing raw pointer. If the underlying `shared_ptr` object may disappear before the `weak_ptr` does, you'll need its expiration check. If this is a bottleneck, see if you can't find a way to guarantee the lifetimes.

Finally back to question 3. I'm answering here without any real knowledge of these types; instead I'm basing it off of how a `shared_ptr` works. Each of `static_pointer_cast`, `dynamic_pointer_cast`, and `const_pointer_cast` return `shared_ptr` instances that point to the same underlying object. Thus they have performed the atomic increment of its reference count. So their overhead is roughly that of a static or dynamic or const cast plus that of a `shared_ptr` copy constructor. The `shared_ptr` part is unlikely to be significant to your overall program, and of the casting part, only the `dynamic_cast` of a `dynamic_pointer_cast` could have a measurable expense (static and const casts are almost entirely compile-time operations).

So once again we are back to ownership and object lifetimes. If you have a clear ownership and that works to give you the lifetime you want, and if you are also writing code that is at the bottleneck of your performance, you will be happier with `unique_ptr` and observing raw pointers (and that's fine; the "rule" is no *owning* raw pointers). But if it's non-bottleneck, or if the object lifetime is not so easy to guarantee, `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` are definitely conveniences with as small a cost as possible to guarantee their semantics.

Comment: Thanks.  This answer gets at the root of what I was asking.  I guess I'll just go with what I've written and see down the road if I'm spending a lot of time casting and copying these pointers, in which case I'll switch to unique pointers and make the weak pointers raw ones.